# Inherit a class that inherits a generic class to make it easier to read

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, generics, unity3d

I'm creating a simple Dependency Injection library for Unity (no constructors available) and I want to use a generic class that implements a generic call for each class that would inherit it allowing changes and scalability.

This would be my generic class

```
// Class with a generic type
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    // Generic method where the dependency is set
    public abstract void Setup(T dependencies);
}
```

Now, I have my dependencies on a interface or any other object, so every single class that would need to implement this class should call `: MyGenericClass<MyDependencies>`. For the long run I feel that this code would be a lot of boilerplate if this will be added to 50+ classes.

Is it a bad practice to write a class that only implements this generic type and sets a type?

Something like this:

```
// Class that sets a type to the generic class
public abstract class MyProjectClass : MyGenericClass<object>
{
}

// Class that directly implements such class
public class MyClassThatImplements : MyProjectClass
{
    private object myDependency;

    // Method with an already defined type
    public override void Setup(object dependencies)
    {
        myDependency = dependencies;
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach for this case?

Comment: Have you looked at the UnityContainer? https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/constructor-injection-using-unity-container  it's already doing DI in Unity.

Comment: I would caution against having everything extend an effective `MyGenericClass<object>` due to the much higher potential for random class cast exceptions.  At least implement the right generic for the right job and let the compiler help you make a correct application.

Comment: Yes, it's OK.  What you are referring to is sometimes called [closing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types). There are some cases where this is frowned upon (e.g. [closing a generic collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)) but otherwise it is a normal part of using generics.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I have looked at it and at [zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) and both are too overkill for my purpose. DI can be a simple pattern, I don't want to import a whole library for it. And this is an example, I would extend an interface probably, not an `object`

Comment: @JavierBullrich I've been using zenject for a while and it's not that complex. Add a scene context, add one of those mono installers and BAM, you can register your classes in there. If that is too overkill, _writing your own DI framework_ most certainly is. In that case you can just use [pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) in a couple of factory classes and be done with it.

Comment: @R.Schmitz on the contrary. My DI framework is some few lines of code (less than 30 lines) and it does the job that I need. Something like zenject is effective when you add the DI later, but, aproaching a project from zero, I believe it's easier to have a basic custom DI.
Wouldn't pure DI be against factory classes?

Comment: @JavierBullrich "_Wouldn't pure DI be against factory classes?_" - Technically factories are orthogonal to DI, but practically you'll probably end up using them either way. Usually injecting the dependencies happens at the composition root, when the app starts running. In pure DI, that's at least one class that creates all the objects (unless you muddle it together with other code, which would be violating single responsibility principle). However, even with a DI framework, something needs to hold the dependencies necessary for objects you want to create later.

Comment: @JavierBullrich I [documented](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/12/16/liberation-of-pure-di-mef-is-not-ioc.html) a case where I had to create a factory using pure DI. The scenario was that I did it with Windsor which was then struck down because the EA only allowed MEF as a container (because ... ???) So I had to rewrite the factory as pure DI. It was a little weird, but also mind-opening because I also thought of factories as something you would do with a container.